# How can i show the wall (feed) of my page to app on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

How can i show the wall (feed) of my page to app on facebook? As i see in the page

1. www.facebook.com/kesha?sk=app_178091127385 and
2. www.facebook.com/pages/Khanduna-Yengu-Nangsu-Amuktang/187317137978077

I want show the wall(feed) of my page to my app of facebook. Please Help me.
I also try and see graph api as below

- graph.facebook.com//feed

But Fail,

Please Help any one.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want to take the wall of your page and show the content of that on another page controlled by an app you have made, so that is the question I will answer.

There are a couple of things you need to do.

Facebook now requires you to have an access_token to get that information. You can get this in two different ways. Either you get your users permission to grab an access_token for them, or you create an access_token for one of the admin users with offline_access and manage_pages permissions.

There are problems with both cases:

1: Getting an access_token per user requires people to give permissions to your app which is quite annoying if they just gain access to the contents of the feed.

2: Having one access_token is also a problem seeing as Facebook puts a limit on how many requests you can make per access_token in a given time.

You need to balance these things out if you want the feed to be shown. Which case would you most likely use? If you don't have many users the second case might be the best, but if you go over the request limit no content will be shown and that could confuse your users.

Anyways.. Once you are past the access_token problem, you can access the information by getting the content from the page:
https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN.

You then get a nice json output you can use. If you are using the Javascript API you can simply use the information here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

If you are ever unsure how to get the information you need there is a nice tool for that developed by Facebook called Graph API Explorer which you can find here:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: I Get You Answer. But How to add the https://graph.facebook.com/<uid>/Feed with the FB.api() and How to display in my api. I also try that all but, graph.facebook.com/<uid>/Feed?accesscode=... Give like this 
 {data:[{id: "115196995171000_244194142271284",from:{name:"Johnny Sharma",id: "1423672279",}to:{data:[{name: ManipuriSms.Co.In",category:"Entertainment",id:"115196995171000",},}
      message: "Wife:eibu kayamna nna thengthabada mangaire",    actions: [{ name: "Comment",},
  
How can i Convert in to facebook like wall html.
Sir, I will be very thank, If you give some example code to do.

Comment: You simply say FB.api(/PAGEID/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN). You will then get a JSON object with the data inside. I am pretty sure you have to style it yourself, but there exists from third party plugins you can use like http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall